# I want to overcome some limitations I faced while using Kafka Spooldir Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have set up Kafka's spooldir connector on a unix machine and it seems to work well. I would like to know if there are a few things that can be done with spooldir

- I want to create multiple directories inside the spooldir-scanning
  file path, create files of the provided format inside them and scan
  those too. How do i accomplish this?
- I do not want the source files to move to different directories after
  completion/error. I tried providing the same path for source, target
  and error but the connector would not accept the value. Any way
  around these?

Comment: You can use Connect FilePulse as an alternative to Spooldir if it doesn't match your need  : https://streamthoughts.github.io/kafka-connect-file-pulse/ . As far as I know, it is not possible to configure Spooldir to not move finished files.

Comment: @fhussonnois thank you for the suggestion. I'm using the connectors on the mainframe and the encoding format there is EBCDIC.. The filepulse connector tries to parse the data to identify the format of data - which it is unable to recognize. Spooldir does not implement any such parsing but has its own limitations as I mentioned. I guess I would have to go with a custom producer

Comment: With Connect FilePulse you can configure different readers : https://streamthoughts.github.io/kafka-connect-file-pulse/docs/developer-guide/file-readers/. If none of those provided suit your needs you can always implement a custom one.